# Changing type name switches compiler warning to compiler error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Here's a C# mystery that maybe someone smarter than me can solve.  I have this line of code:

```
static private bool AddGoalToPlan(SqlConnection connection, string userName, Goal goal, RecommendationManager.Sources source, int? recommendationId, int topThree)
```

The `source` parameter of this method is unused, however the code compiles just fine.  However, I then rename the type `RecommendationManager.Sources` to `RecommendationManager.RecommendationSources` - nothing else changes.  Now, I get the compiler error:

> error CA1801: Parameter source of method AddGoalToPlan is never used.
>   Remove the parameter or use it in the method body.

Why does changing the type move this from a warning to a compiler error?  My best guess is that the error is somehow suppressed (maybe in some rule file somewhere?) and the suppression is tied to the typenames.  However, I couldn't find anything that would support this theory.

PS - Obviously the fix is just remove the unused parameter and be done with it, so this question is mostly for my intellectual curiosity as an engineer.

Comment: Is the type of the parameter 'source' that is expected in the method header of type 'RecommendationManager.Sources' or 'RecommendationManager.RecommendationSources'?

Comment: The difference is "CS" vs. "CA".  CS for CSharp compiler warnings/errors.  CA for Code Analysis results.  I think we need to know more to drill down on why, though.

Comment: I do have a `.ruleset` file, but the only reference to that error code is: `<Rule Id="CA1801" Action="Warning" />`

Comment: The ruleset file also has no reference to `RecommendationManager.Sources` or `AddGoalToPlan`

Comment: Is the first one a warning or an info? Do you have "Treat warnings as errors" enabled?

Comment: Mystery solved with the help of another colleague.  Posted the cause below!

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out!  In the `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file there was the following line:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Build", "CA1801:Parameter source of method AddGoalToPlan is never used. Remove the parameter or use it in the method body.", Justification = "Excluding pre-existing violations to create baseline", Scope = "member", Target = "~M:GoalAssistant.AddGoalToPlan(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,System.String,Goal,RecommendationManager.Sources,System.Nullable{System.Int32},System.Int32)~System.Boolean")]
```

This line references the old type `RecommendationManager.Sources` by name.